# Use the ORSSerialPort Library with Combine and SwiftUi. Problem by trying to subscribe a Key-Value Observing(KVO) object

Tags: swiftui, key-value-observing, combine, orsserialport

I am trying to integrate the ORSSerialPort framework with Combine into SwiftUi. [ORSSerialPort GitHub](https://github.com/armadsen/ORSSerialPort)

ORSSerialPort implements  Key-Value Observing(KVO) and a Delegate Pattern. In his example, he works with the Delegate Pattern and UIKit. I will use Combine and SwiftUI.  Not the Delegate Pattern.

Because the ORSSerialPort is a KVO Object, it should be possible ORSSerialPort variables to subscribe, but her is my Problem. It will not work.  I don't know why.

what i try:

```
@Published var isOpen: String = ""
var orsSerialPort: ORSSerialPort = ORSSerialPort(path: "/dev/cu.usbmodem146101")!
var publisher: NSObject.KeyValueObservingPublisher<ORSSerialPort, Bool>
var isOpenSub: AnyCancellable?

init(){
    publisher = orsSerialPort.publisher(for: \.isOpen)
    isOpenSub = publisher
        .map{ (x) -> String in return "Is \(x ? "Opend":"Close" )" }
        .assign(to: \.isOpen, on: self)
}
```

The publisher is trigger always one time, and that is by the init. If I close and open the port with my function, it will not trigger again.

```
  func cloes(){
    orsSerialPort.close()
}

func open(){
    orsSerialPort.open()
}
```

For Debugging I try this to the the Stream. And I will see again that the Publisher will always trigger only one time. But the Port is closing and opining.

```
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
    print("subScribeIsOpen complet")
    switch completion {
        case .finished:
            print("subScribeIsOpen complet")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("subScribeIsOpen fail")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }, receiveValue: { value in
         print("subScribeIsOpen receive \(value)")
         self.isOpen = value
    })
```

My Demo Code

```
import Foundation
import ORSSerial
import Combine
import SwiftUI
class ORSSerialPortCombine: ObservableObject {
    @Published var status: String = ""
    @Published var isOpen: String = ""
    var orsSerialPort: ORSSerialPort = ORSSerialPort(path: "/dev/cu.usbmodem146101")!
    var publisher: NSObject.KeyValueObservingPublisher<ORSSerialPort, Bool>
    var isOpenSub: AnyCancellable?
    init(){
        publisher = orsSerialPort.publisher(for: \.isOpen)
        isOpenSub = publisher
            .map{ (x) -> String in return "Is \(x ? "Opend":"Close" )" }
//            .assign(to: \.isOpen, on: self)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                print("subScribeIsOpen complet")
                switch completion {
                    case .finished:
                        print("subScribeIsOpen complet")
                    case .failure(let error):
                        print("subScribeIsOpen fail")
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }, receiveValue: { value in
                print("subScribeIsOpen receive \(value)")
                self.isOpen = value
            })
    }
    func cloes(){
        orsSerialPort.close()
    }
    func open(){
        orsSerialPort.open()
    }
    func updateStatus(){
        status = "Serial port is \(orsSerialPort.isOpen ? "Opend":"Close" )"
    }
}
struct ORSSerialPortCombineView: View{
    @ObservedObject var model = ORSSerialPortCombine()
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Text( model.isOpen )
            HStack{
                Button("Close") { model.cloes() }
                Button("Open") { model.open() }
                Button("Staus") { model.updateStatus() }
            }
            Text( model.status )

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `isOpen` property on `ORSSerialPort` is not KVO compliant. You can’t observe it with key value observing. If this would be useful to you, please file an issue: https://github.com/armadsen/ORSSerialPort/issues/new/choose

Comment: Thank for this answer. I will create my idea as an issue when i have finished my thoughts.